# While loop in R giving "argument is of length zero" error

Tags: r, loops, while-loop

I've been doing some topic modelling (LDA), and I've created a matrix of the posterior probabilities that each document (in this case, a day's worth of tweets). I'd like to measure how focused each day's discussion is, so I'd like to see how many topics are needed to "explain" some percentage of that day's discussion. I'm able to do it for a small number of topics:

```
thresh<-.98
distribution98 <- function(x){
  if (x[k]>thresh){x<-1}
  else if(x[k]+x[k-1]>thresh){x<-2}
  else if(x[k]+x[k-1]+x[k-2]>thresh){x<-3}
  else {x<-4}}
apply(ndx, 2, short)
```

Where ndx is my matrix of posteriors (each column is a day, each row is a topic and I've sorted each column from lowest to higherst) and this particular function is looking for how many topics are needed to explain 98% of the discussion.

I'm trying to write a function that can do this for any number of topics, and I'm getting an error message that I don't understand:

```
k<-100
results<-vector(mode="numeric", length=324)
short<- function(x){ for (j in 1:ncol(ndx)) {
  i<-0
  total<-0
  while(total < thresh){
    total<-(total+x[k-i])
    i<-(1+i)
    results[j]<-i
  }
}
}
apply(ndx, 2, short)
Error in while (total < thresh) { : argument is of length zero
```

My thought was that this would leave me with a vector (result) that was just a record of how large i had to get in order to push total above thresh. But I don't understand the error--total and thresh are both numeric, so total < thresh either has to be true or false?

Comment: `while(NULL) 1` reproduces the error. So I guess you assign "total" to a null in one step of your loop. Explain better what do you want to do, I think you don't need a loop here.

Comment: Check that `total+x[k-i]` isn't evaluating to NA.  If that's supposed to be k = total length of `x`, also, then use the `length()` function there instead of a variable.   (As an aside, to the experienced R crowd - is this kind of programming (using what I'd call 'global' variables) normal in R?  It was specifically called out as something that made R useful in the Hopkins online class I took (due to lexical scoping), but it seems to go against normal programming rules.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are looking for something like this :

```
## giving a vector x and a threshold .thresh
## returns the min index, where the cumulative sum of x >  .thresh
get_min_threshold <- 
function(x,.thresh)
  max(which(cumsum(x[order(x)]) < .thresh))+1

## apply the function to each column of the data.frame
lapply(ndx,get_min_threshold,.thresh=.98)
```

Comment: The function you wrote works perfectly, but when I applied it using lapply the way you suggest it gave me a maximal result for each column. Doing it as xxx<-apply(ndx, 2, get_min_threshold,.thresh=.98) works. Thanks!